# Incrementally add number to all elements with same class name using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I couldn't get the lingo right in order to find out how to do this. On my page I have numerous span elements with the class "z-title". I would like to add an additional class to these elements which includes an incremental number, for example

from this

```
<span class="z-title">Hello</span>
<span class="z-title">Hello</span>
<span class="z-title">Hello</span>
```

to this

```
<span class="z-title tab1">Hello</span>
<span class="z-title tab2">Hello</span>
<span class="z-title tab3">Hello</span>
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery's [`.addClass()` function](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/) can accept a callback function as an argument, in which case that callback will be called once per element in the jQuery object. The callback receives the index of the current element as an argument, and the string value returned from the callback should be the name of the class to add to that element.

The element indices start at zero, but of course you can add one to each index to get the class names you want:

```js
$(".z-title").addClass(function(i) { return "tab" + (i + 1) })
```

```css
.tab1 { color: red; }
.tab2 { color: blue; }
.tab3 { color: green; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="z-title">Hello</span>
<span class="z-title">Hello</span>
<span class="z-title">Hello</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery each function to loop through all the elements with the class name "z-title" and add class to it by incrementing the index value, the code is as follows :

```
 $(".z-title").each(function(index){
    $(this).addClass('tab'+(index+1));
  })
```